# R - Sample function doesn't seem to be working in loop

Tags: r

So, I'm relatively new to R and have the following problem:
I want to run 1000 generations of a population of some organism. At each generation there is a certain probability to change from one environment to the other (there are just two different "environments").
Now, the code works just fine and I do get the desired results. However one small issue that still needs to be resolved is that for every run, the initial environment seems to be set at environment 1 even though  I defined the initial environment to be randomly sampled (should be either environment 1 OR 2; you can find this in line 12 of the second block of code).
If anybody could help me resolve this issue, I would be very thankful.

```
simulate_one_gen_new <- function(K, N_total_init, N_wt, N_generalist, N_specialist, growth_wt, growth_generalist, growth_specialist, mut_rate) {
  scaling <- min(K/(N_wt + N_generalist + N_specialist),1)
  # draw offspring according to Poisson distribution
  offsp_wt <- rpois(1, scaling * N_wt * growth_wt)
  offsp_generalist <- rpois(1, scaling * N_generalist * growth_generalist)
  offsp_specialist <- rpois(1, scaling * N_specialist * growth_specialist)
  # draw new mutants according to Poisson distribution
  mut_wt_to_generalist <- rpois(1, N_wt * (mut_rate/2))
  mut_wt_to_specialist <- rpois(1, N_wt * (mut_rate/2))
 
  
  # determine new population sizes of wild type and mutant  
  N_wt_new <- max(offsp_wt - mut_wt_to_specialist - mut_wt_to_generalist, 0)
  N_generalist_new <-  max(offsp_generalist + mut_wt_to_generalist,0)
  N_specialist_new <-  max(offsp_specialist + mut_wt_to_specialist,0)
  N_total_new <- N_wt_new + N_generalist_new + N_specialist_new
  return(c(N_total_new, N_wt_new, N_generalist_new, N_specialist_new))
}

# Test the function
print(simulate_one_gen_new(100,100,100,0,0,0.9,1.0,1.1,0.001))
```

The code block above is needed to simulate one single generation.

```
simulate_pop_new <- function(K, N_total_init,N_init_wt, 
                             growth_vec1, growth_vec2, growth_vec3, 
                             mut_rate, switch_prob) {
  # determine that there are no mutants present at time 0
  N_init_generalist <- 0
  N_init_specialist <- 0
  # Create the vector in which to save the results, including the index of the environment
  pop_vector <- c(N_total_init,N_init_wt, N_init_generalist, N_init_specialist, 1)
  # initiate the variables
  pop_new <- c(N_total_init, N_init_wt, N_init_generalist, N_init_specialist)
  # determine that the first environment is either 1 or 2
  env_temp <- sample(1:2, size = 1, replace = T)
  tmax <- 1000
  j <- 0

  # run the simulation until generation t_max
  for (i in 1:tmax) {
    # redefine the current population one generation later
    pop_new <- c(simulate_one_gen_new(K,pop_new[1],pop_new[2],pop_new[3],pop_new[4], growth_vec1[env_temp],growth_vec2[env_temp], growth_vec3[env_temp],mut_rate),env_temp)
    # add the new population sizes to the output vector
    pop_vector <- rbind(pop_vector,pop_new)
    # determine whether environmental switch occurs and make it happen
    env_switch <- rbinom(1,1,switch_prob)
    if (env_switch==1)
      {
      if(env_temp==1) env_temp <- 2
      else env_temp <- 1
    }
    
    # condition to stop the simulation before t_max: either the population has only one of the two mutants left, or the whole population goes extinct
    if ((pop_new[2] == 0 & pop_new[3] == 0) | (pop_new[2] == 0 & pop_new[4] == 0)){j=j+1} 
    if (j == 100) break #here we let it run 100 generations longer after the conditions above are met
  }
  
  # define the row and column names of the output vector
  rownames(pop_vector) <- (0:length(pop_vector[1]))[1:length(pop_vector[,1])] # note that the vector has to be cut if the simulation stopped early
  colnames(pop_vector) <- c("total","wt","generalist","specialist","env")
  # return the result
  return(pop_vector)    
}

# Test the function and plot the result

# create your simulation data
output <- simulate_pop_new(1000,1000,1000,c(0.98,0.99),c(1.04,1.02),c(0.96,1.1),0.001,0.5)

# show the last few lines of the data table
print(tail(output))

# determine x axis range 
x_range <- 0:(length(output[,1])-1)

# Create data frame from output (or just rename it)
df <- data.frame(output)

# Add a new column to our output that simply shows the Generations
df$Generation<-1:nrow(df)

# Manually create data frame where the genotypes are not separate but all in one column. Note that we need to repeat/ add together all other values since our "Genotype" column will be three times longer.
Genotype <- rep(c("wt", "generalist", "specialist"), each = length(output[,1]))
PopSize <- c(df$wt, df$generalist, df$specialist)
Generation <- rep(df$Generation, 3) 
environment <- rep(df$env, 3)  

# Let's also create a column solely for the total population
All_Genotypes <- df$generalist + df$wt + df$specialist
N_tot <- rep(All_Genotypes, 3)

# Create a new data frame containing the modified columns which we will be using for plotting
single_run <- data.frame(Generation, Genotype, PopSize, N_tot, environment)
print(tail(single_run))
```

Above is the second block of code which now simulates 1000 generations.

Comment: If you are referring to the 1 for `env` in the first row of `output`, it comes from line 5 of `simulate_pop_new` where you explicitly initiate `pop_vector` with this value.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I really did miss that I had defined it in the `pop_vector`. The issue is thereby resolved.